# Как работает DataFrame.Merge

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, объединение

Есть 2 DataFrame, которые создаются вот так:

```
cols = ['User_Url','id']
cols_1=['User_Url_1','id']

list_of_url = [pd.Series(['/_c/YwrVrj_29IVZDmKxglT53wo7Pk8.html',1],index=cols), pd.Series(['/gate/cart-list.xml?sk=y5fc6079b758f5a4e3646a8',2],index=cols),pd.Series(['/gate/cart-list.xml?sk=yd6558780959d5130b32e1a',''],index=cols),pd.Series(['/gate/cart-list.xml?sk=y5fc6079b758f5a4e3646a8',2],index=cols)]

Url = pd.DataFrame(list_of_url, columns=cols)

list_of_url_1 = [pd.Series(['/gate/cart-list.xml?sk=yd6558780959d5130b32e1a',3],index=cols_1), pd.Series(['/gate/cart-list.xml?sk=yd6558780959d5130b32e1a',3],index=cols_1),pd.Series(['/offers.xml?modelid=8464553&hid=4165204&how=ap',44],index=cols_1),pd.Series(['clicked',5],index=cols_1)]

Url_1 = pd.DataFrame(list_of_url_1, columns=cols_1)
```

и содержат такие данные: 
1-й DataFrame (Url)

```
                                         User_Url id
0            /_c/YwrVrj_29IVZDmKxglT53wo7Pk8.html  1
1  /gate/cart-list.xml?sk=y5fc6079b758f5a4e3646a8  2
2  /gate/cart-list.xml?sk=yd6558780959d5130b32e1a   
3  /gate/cart-list.xml?sk=y5fc6079b758f5a4e3646a8  2
```

2-й DataFrame (Url_1)

```
                                       User_Url_1  id
0  /gate/cart-list.xml?sk=yd6558780959d5130b32e1a   3
1  /gate/cart-list.xml?sk=yd6558780959d5130b32e1a   3
2  /offers.xml?modelid=8464553&hid=4165204&how=ap  44
clicked   5
```

Я бы хотела получить столбец, который включает в себя те ссылки, которые есть и в Url, и в Url_1. На выходе:

```
                                       User_Url_fin  id
 0  /gate/cart-list.xml?sk=yd6558780959d5130b32e1a   3
```

Я сделала это с помощью Merge

```
df = (Url.merge(Url_1, left_on='User_Url',right_on='User_Url_1', how='inner'))
```

Всегда ли Merge с параметром inner будет объединять столбцы на основе значений, содержащихся и первом объединяемом столбце, и во втором?

Comment: В `Url` в соответствующей строке отсутствует слэш в начале...

Comment: Спасибо, я подправила, все получилось. Просто меня интересует несколько более общий вопрос по-поводу работы merge: всегда ли он так будет работать?

Comment: Я очень недавно начала изучать питон и библиотеку pandas. Именно поэтому работа многих функций не совсем ясна для меня

Comment: Вы можете уточнить суть вопроса?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если при вызове [DataFrame.merge()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) / [pd.merge()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html?highlight=merge#pandas.merge) не указать столбцы, по которым должно происходить объединение, то объединение будет происходить по всем столбцам с совпадающими наименованиями.

Если в двух фреймах совпадают наименования нескольких столбцов, а объединять их надо по меньшему числу столбцов, то следует использовать параметр `on=['join_col_name1','join_col_name2']`.

Параметры `left_on` и `right_on` служат для указания столбца(ов), по которым объединяются DataFrame'ы, в том случае если мы объединяем столбцы с различающимися наименованиями.

[Примеры](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#brief-primer-on-merge-methods-relational-algebra)